# How to translate java regular expression to javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I will like to translate the Java Regex

```
(\\\p{Upper}{2})(\\\d{2})([\\\p{Upper}\\\p{Digit}]{1,30}+)
```

to JavaScript Regex. I tried

```
([A-Z]{2})([0-9]{2})([A-Z][0-9]{1,30}+)
```

This translation wouldn't compile. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have separated last `[\\\p{Upper}\\\p{Digit}]` into `[A-Z][0-9]` but it should be `[A-Z0-9]`

Just try with:

```
([A-Z]{2})([0-9]{2})([A-Z0-9]{1,30}+)
```

You can also replace `0-9` with `\d`, so:

```
([A-Z]{2})(\d{2})([A-Z\d]{1,30}+)
```

Comment: Thanks hsz for your prompt assistance. The answer as it is didn't compile. I had to move the "+" out of the closed bracket to make the regex wellformed. Does this modification alters the basics of this regex? I don't seems to see any.